# 3 dot/settings in top bar buttons

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, settings

When in some apps, there are those 3 dots in the top right of the app, on the action bar (not the home buttons), which allow for more options. In my app I have on, but I do not know how to make it do a method when it is clicked. Do I use `android:onClick="METHOD_NAME` ? Or do I need to setup a button variable in my activity class and setup and onClickListener? I have already tried both but I may be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

That three dots are the menu in the action bar. They are always shown on devices without a menu key.

See also the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Three dots are called Overflow(very aptly named) and to use them you need to use ActionBar which is the top long, horizontal bar showing icons, other buttons along with the Overflow button.

Now in some devices where there is no physical menu button you will always see Overflow button.

Go through Docs and tutorials related to ActionBar but keep one thing in mind that ActionBar is only available for devices with android above HoneyComb. For android devices below 3.0 such as GingerBread or Froyo you will have to use compatibility libraries, so that will be an additional task.

And most notable libraries for this purpose are ActionBarSherlock and AppCompat.